# Why Django Rest Framework doesn't parse iso-8061 generated by JSON.net?

Tags: json.net, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework to consume an API posts that from a .NET server.

The iso-8061 date time generated by JSON.net looks like:

```
"doTime": "2016-10-25T20:26:46.1726639Z"
```

My serializer is more or less:

```
class DoStuffSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    timeformats = ["iso-8061", "rfc-3339", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"]
    whereStuff = AddressSerializer(required=True)
    doTime = serializers.DateTimeField(input_formats=timeformats, required=False)
```

and the serialization error:

```
{
    "doTime": [
        "Datetime has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead:
            iso-8061,
            rfc-3339,
            YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.uuuuuuZ, 
            YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ, 
            YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.uuuuuu, 
            YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss"
    ]
}
```

(formatted for clarity)

I've tried to account for the extra decimal places, but that's not working, as the decimals from JSON.net version of iso-8061 are going past microseconds and Python's strptime is choking.

```
.1726639z
.uuuuuuZ
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Probably because ISO 8061 deals with Alpine Ski Bindings (https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:8061:ed-4:v1:en), which has absolutely **NOTHING** to do with programming. Maybe you meant 8601?

Comment: (•_•)    ( •_•)>⌐■-■    (⌐■_■)

Comment: @MarcB can you put that as the answer?

Comment: With a heavy heart, I cast my typo close vote. May this hilarity live on [on the internet archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20221125062609/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250028/why-django-rest-framework-doesnt-parse-iso-8061-generated-by-json-net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because ISO 8061 deals with Alpine Ski Bindings (http://iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:8061:ed-4:v1:en), which has absolutely NOTHING to do with programming. Maybe you meant `8601`?

Comment: dyslexia strikes again!